# Any way to send message to DISCORD by url?

Tags: discord

With **telegram** it's possible to send message to channel using just bare url:

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot[BOT_API_KEY]/sendMessage?chat_id=[MY_CHANNEL_NAME]&text=[MY_MESSAGE_TEXT]
```

Anything like that possible with Discord? So, to send message using a plain URL (get) request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to [send a message to a channel as the bot](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#create-message), you will send a POST message to the endpoint `/channels/{channel.id}/messages` but also need to [authenticate/identify yourself](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway#identify), first:

> Before using this endpoint, you must connect to and identify with a gateway at least once.

However, you can do something similar: Setup and [send a message using a Webhook](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/webhook#execute-webhook) that doesn't require an authentication process before the requiest.

You can setup a webhook for a channel in the channel settings under `Integrations`>`WebHooks`. You can there click on `Copy Webhook URL` in order to copy the URL.

The URL will look like this: `https://discord.com/api/webhooks/<Webhook ID>/<Webhook token>`.

You can then [send a POST request to the webhook url](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/webhook#execute-webhook) with the message payload.

It can be a JSON/Form payload with the following fields (copied from [the docs](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/webhook#execute-webhook)):

```
FIELD             TYPE                    DESCRIPTION                                              REQUIRED
content           string                  the message contents (up to 2000 characters)  one of content, file, embeds
username          string                  override the default username of the webhook  false
avatar_url        string                  override the default avatar of the webhook    false
tts               boolean                 true if this is a TTS message                 false
file              file contents           the contents of the file being sent           one of content, file, embeds
embeds            array of up to          10 embed objects  embedded rich content       one of content, file, embeds
payload_json      string                  See message create                            multipart/form-data only
allowed_mentions  allowed mention object  allowed mentions for the message              false
```

Comment: But you can access a webhook with a sumple `curl` command or send normal messages with two `curl` commands (even if you may need to use a variable). Another option is to create a web server that forwards the GET requests as POST requests with the required information.

Comment: Well, that is still irrelevant. the whole point of the topic was to know if there is a way doing that without special webserver (either `curl` is part of webserver tool, and not a part of most other applications that only UrlPing with Get abilities only). anyway thanks for taking time.